# Finding duplicates and creating a mapping

Tags: python, algorithm

Following example:

```
I have a dictionary which is as below
string_id1 : "calvin klein"
string_id2: "calvin klin"
string_id3: "CALVIN KLEIN"
string_id4: "ccalvin klein"
```

Above dictionary values are same without some spelling. Using Fuzzy mathing, I will identify whether given two strings are the same. If they are duplicates, I need to fallback to using one standard string. In this case, I will recognize calvin Klein is the fallback string (associated to string_id1 as well first identified string). So, I want to map string_id1 as the usable string to other strings. Expected output:

```
string_id1: string_id1
string_id2: string_id1
string_id3: string_id1
string_id4: string_id1
```

Which is best algorithm to create such mappings which also works for large data in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store them in a trie with the correct string(s) as data at every node. You can google for more info.

Storing strings 2,3,4 in trie with every data as possible correct strings will solve this. You can implement a typeahead search similar to quora or amazon (where invalid string entry is not possible because it won't return any results.)

Tomorrow if you want to add carlson davind to the strings list, when they type c you show both carlson david & calvin kevin, when they type cc you only show calvn kevin.